# Angular - Use form post values in controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, post, scope

I'm writing my first application in AngularJS, and I'm new to javascript. I have a simple question:

How do I use POST values from an html form in an angular controller?

I have a form (i've stripped out the css and validation stuff for ease of reading):

```
<form name="signupForm" novalidate>

                <input type="text" placeholder="Name..." ng-model="name" name="name" required />

                <input type="email" name="email" ng-model="email" placeholder="Email..." required>

                <input type="password" placeholder="Password..." ng-model="password" name="password" required ng-minlength="7" ng-maxlength="50"/>

                <button type="button" ng-click="auth.signup()">Sign Up</button>

</form>
```

I have a controller (no errors), with a function which looks a bit like this:

```
    function SignupController($http, $scope, $rootScope, $location) {

          vm.signup = function(name, email, password, onSuccess, onError) {

              $http.post('http://myapi.com/api/authenticate/signup',
              {
                  name: name,
                  email: email,
                  password: password
              }).then(function(response) {
                // etc 
              }); 
}
```

Now, how do I assign the values name, email, password from the form to name, email, password in the controller?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set the input with ng-model="email", then you can access those variable values in controller by just calling $scope.email.

> **Case-1: For single value**

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" ng-model="email" />
```

**Angular Controller**

```
console.log($scope.email);
```

> **Case-2: For multiple values**

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" ng-model="user.firstname" />
<input type="text" ng-model="user.lastname" />
<input type="text" ng-model="user.email" />
```

**Angular Controller**

```
//This will print the all the values (firstname, lastname, email) contains user as object.
console.log($scope.user);
```

Please check this working snippet to see the real time example

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('FormCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
  $scope.user = {};
  $scope.signup = function(){
      console.log($scope.user);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp">
  <form name="signupForm" ng-controller="FormCtrl" ng-submit="signup()">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Name..." ng-model="user.name" name="name" required />
  <input type="email" name="email" ng-model="user.email" placeholder="Email..." required>
  <input type="password" placeholder="Password..." ng-model="user.password" name="password" required ng-minlength="7" ng-maxlength="50"/>
  <button type="submit">Sign Up</button>
  </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use $scope for binding ng-model's value as shown as follow...

```
          $scope.signup = function() {
             data={
                      name: $scope.name,
                      email: $scope.email,
                      password: $scope.password
                  }
              $http.post('http://myapi.com/api/authenticate/signup',data).then(function(response) {
                // etc 
                     });
```

Answer (score 1):

Three ways you can do

**Type 1**   With individual params

HTML

```
   <form name="signupForm" novalidate>
     <input type="text" placeholder="Name..." ng-model="name" name="name" required />
     <input type="email" name="email" ng-model="email" placeholder="Email..." required />
     <input type="password" placeholder="Password..." ng-model="password" name="password" ng-minlength="7" ng-maxlength="50" required/>
     <button type="button" ng-click="auth.signup(name, email, password)">Sign Up</button>
  </form>
```

JS

```
vm.signup = function(name, email, password) {
      $http.post('http://myapi.com/api/authenticate/signup',
      {
          name: name,
          email: email,
          password: password
      }).then(function(response) { });              
    }
```

**Type 2**   With object as param

HTML

```
     <form name="signupForm" novalidate>
       <input type="text" placeholder="Name..." ng-model="user.name" name="name" required />
      <input type="email" name="email" ng-model="user.email" placeholder="Email..." required />
      <input type="password" placeholder="Password..." ng-model="user.password" name="password" ng-minlength="7" ng-maxlength="50" required/>
      <button type="button" ng-click="auth.signup(user)">Sign Up</button>
    </form>
```

JS

```
vm.signup = function(data) {
      $http.post('http://myapi.com/api/authenticate/signup', data)
        .then(function(response) {
      });              
  }
```

**Type 3**    Using $scope

HTML

```
     <form name="signupForm" novalidate>
       <input type="text" placeholder="Name..." ng-model="user.name" name="name" required />
       <input type="email" name="email" ng-model="user.email" placeholder="Email..." required />
       <input type="password" placeholder="Password..." ng-model="user.password" name="password" ng-minlength="7" ng-maxlength="50" required/>
       <button type="button" ng-click="auth.signup()">Sign Up</button>
    </form>
```

JS

```
vm.signup = function() {
        $http.post('http://myapi.com/api/authenticate/signup', $scope.data)
            .then(function(response) {
      });              
 }
```

It will work in all these ways.

Checkout the working demo of best solution among these three
Demo: https://jsbin.com/rimemi/25/edit?html,js,console,output

Answer (score 1):

HTML

```
<form name="signupForm" novalidate>

            <input type="text" placeholder="Name..." ng-model="user.name" name="name" required />

            <input type=“email" name="email" ng-model="user.email" placeholder="Email..." required>

            <input type="password" placeholder="Password..." ng-model="user.password" name="password" required ng-minlength="7" ng-maxlength="50"/>

            <button type="button" ng-click="auth.signup()">Sign Up</button>
```

JS

```
function SignupController($http, $scope, $rootScope, $location) {
   $scope.user={};
  vm.signup = function(name, email, password, onSuccess, onError) {

      $http.post('http://myapi.com/api/authenticate/signup',
      {
          name: $scope.user.name,
          email: $scope.user.email,
          password: $scope.user.password
      }).then(function(response) {
        // etc
```

Answer (score 1):

In your html

```
<form name="signupForm" novalidate ng-submit="vm.signup()">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Name..." ng-model="name" name="vm.user.name" required />
    <input type=“email" name="email" ng-model="vm.user.email" placeholder="Email..." required>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Password..." ng-model="vm.user.password" name="password" required ng-minlength="7" ng-maxlength="50"/>
    <button type="submit">Sign Up</button>
</form>
```

In your controller

```
function SignupController($http, $scope, $rootScope, $location) {
   vm.user = {};

   vm.signup = function() {
       // validate here

       // send data
       $http
          .post('http://myapi.com/api/authenticate/signup', vm.user)
          .then(function(response) {
            // handle success 
           });
   };
}
```